# Machine Learning and R textbook reference

Tags: r, machine-learning, references

I am asking for a book reference to further my studies in machine learning with the R programming language. Feel free to reference multiple books that are just machine learning or just R programming. I understand some basic concepts, but I think I am having trouble applying my knowledge to get real results.

For example, I would like to test my knowledge out with some exercises from real datasets. Questions I would like to answer are: How much more accuracy can I gain by fine-tuning a regularization parameter? What is a good accuracy for a particular problem (in practice, what is the intuitive feel)? What are some common methods to improve my accuracy w.r.t features? How do I find the best value for a regularization parameter? Which machine learning algorithm will work well for this problem?

My programming knowledge of R is the basic control structures and some of the functional features such as the `apply` function to iterate over a data-frame. I also know some basics of the data-frame data structure and the list data structure.

I can apply a bunch of machine learning algorithms with R, but I do not know enough to tackle a wide variety of problems. I am hoping to gain some practical experience from book exercises as well as good understandings of the main algorithms. I understand math (calculus, graph theory, and probability) but I probably need a refresher in certain areas.

- In summary, what book would you recommend for someone interested in gaining practical knowledge in Machine Learning and using the R programming language?

Comment: See [Machine Learning with R](http://books.google.ca/books?id=ZQu8AQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=machine+learning+with+r+brett+lantz&hl=en&sa=X&ei=UWh4U-XwMsGxyASXtYGICQ&ved=0CDgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=machine%20learning%20with%20r%20brett%20lantz&f=false) by Brett Lantz.

Comment: This is a good place to start: www.RDataMining.com. Still, R in a nutshell it is a pretty good book to get started. It goes beyond the syntax, and has devotes chapters to each step in the whole data analysis pipe: data inspection, cleaning, visualization, statistical analysis and machine learning.

Comment: [Here](http://bayesianthink.blogspot.com/2012/12/the-best-books-to-learn-probability.html#.U3raMxVx05k) is a list of books that deal with probability which are crucial for machine learning/modelling. Also in that list are some books that deal with doing the same in R. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 7):

[Applied Predictive Modeling](http://appliedpredictivemodeling.com/), by Max Kuhn (who wrote the caret package) and Kjell Johnson, is very practical with tons of code and real world datasets.

[Practical Data Science with R](http://www.manning.com/zumel/) by Nina Zumel and John Mount is an excellent new book that broadly covers data science, including ML, at an introductory-to-intermediate level.

[An Introduction to Statistical Learning with Applications in R](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/) by Gareth James, Daniela Witten, Trevor Hastie and Robert Tibshirani is a lucid introductory book written by many of the same authors as the more advanced [Elements of Statistical Learning](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/).  Hastie and Tibshirani should be familiar names as they have also made major contributions to machine learning and R (packages including glmnet, gam, hierNet, etc). Both ISL and ESL are available as PDFs online but I personally think they're also worth getting in hardcopy.

For improving understanding of R as a programming language, I like [The Art of R Programming: A Tour of Statistical Software Design](http://www.nostarch.com/artofr.htm) by Norman Matloff.  I also strongly recommend Hadley Wickham's in-progress book [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/).

For people who are beginning to learn statistics, I often recommend Introductory Statistics with R by Peter Dalgaard.  For more advanced statistics, I have benefited from Cosma Shalizi's online draft textbook [Advanced Data Analysis from an Elementary Point of View](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/ADAfaEPoV/).

(I have yet to read and can't comment one way or another on [Data Mining with R](http://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~ltorgo/DataMiningWithR/) by Luis Torgo or [Machine Learning with R](http://www.packtpub.com/machine-learning-with-r/book) by Brett Lantz.)